# Change the channel color in Dopesheet/Graph Editor

Tags: interface, customization

I am trying to change the color of the channels in the *DopeSheet*, *Graph Editor* and *Timeline*.
Can somebody tell me where to change the yellow-ish color so I can actually read the channel names?
I tried finding it in *Preferences-Theme-Graph Editor*, but it isn't there.
I'm using the dark Theme in Blender 2.90 on Ubuntu20.04

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you've assigned colors to your bones in *Pose* mode:

[image]

You can disable it in the *Graph Editor* > header menu > *View > Show Group Colors* (I don't know why it is not available in the *Dope Sheet* though):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To change the actual text colour from grey, Edit > Themes> Dope Sheet > Theme Space List and click on the current grey colour. I've changed mine to black under 2.8.

[image]

I've not looked at the settings for the other editors but I guess they'll be the same.