# How to disable bone colors from appearing on Timeline tracks (and Dopesheet, Graph Editor)

Tags: animation, bones

Since a few days in 3.6.4 my bones group colors are making the timeline editor's channels unreadable. It must be an option that I somehow turned on, as it wasn't the case before or when opening the same file in 3.5. But I can't find this option in any menu like View, nor the preferences (but I didn't touch them when it appeared.)

Here is how it should look, readable:

[image]

And here is how it looks in all my files now, unreadable:
(if it's an option it should be saved in the file, strange that it poped in all files suddenly..)

[image]

Thanks !

Also, "Show Bone Color" would solve it, but it does not exist anymore as an option it seems:
[image]

Comment: Hello please check the answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206210/change-the-channel-color-in-dopesheet-graph-editor

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes I saw this post but it seems to be outdated, the "Show Bone Color" option does not exist anymore it seems, I don't have it in the graph or any other timeline editors (can't paste the screenshot.)
So my question could also be, why does "Show Bone Color" not a thing anymore ?

Comment: OK, weird, maybe in the Preferences > Animation > F-Curves > uncheck Chanel Group Colors?

Comment: that's it, thanks a lot ! It's probably one of these things that were moved from the view options in the grapth editor, to the preferences, like the option to show only selected curves, that I was using all the time in the view panel, and that's now inaccessible in the pref so no quick favorites anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences > Animation > F-Curves > uncheck Chanel Group Colors

Thanks @moonboots !
(no idea how that could have toggled on its own..)