# How to change channel color in graph editor in blender 4.0?

Tags: interface, bones, graph-editor

I did set bone color both in editor and pose mode.

In graph editor I do not see option for "Use group color" or any similar option.

Is it even supported in new blender?

View menu

[image: View Menu]

Full graph layout

[image: Blender Graph preview]

###### Link to outdated question

Similar question [from blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206210/change-the-channel-color-in-dopesheet-graph-editor) is outdated.